# Image file is not uploading in android app ftp server

Tags: android, image, file, upload

Image file is not uploading on server in android application.Is there any problem in code

```
public String UploadFile(String filename, String localFilePath, String path) throws Exception {
     String hostName = ftphost;
     String username = ftpusername;
     String password = ftppassword;
     FTPClient ftp = null;
     InputStream in = null;         
     try{            
         ftp = new FTPClient();
         ftp.connect(hostName);
         ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
         ftp.setConnectTimeout(180000);
         ftp.login(username, password);
         ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

         ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(path);

         int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
         System.out.println("Reçu de réponse de la connexion FTP:" + reply);

         if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
             System.out.println("succès connecté");
         }

         File f1 = new File(localFilePath);
         in = new FileInputStream(f1);

         ftp.storeFile(filename, in);
         ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
         System.out.println("SUCCÈS");

         ftp.logout();
         ftp.disconnect();
         return "OK";
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return "Fail";
     }
}
```

Comment: here is the full code: